# remove non alphabet chars from the beginning and the end of the string

Tags: python, regex, string

I am pretty new to regular expressions. I want to clean up a string from non alphabet chars that are positioned at the beginning and at the end of the string. For example if I have the following string: 
`.,How are you? I am good, thanks!.,`

I would like to get: 
`How are you? I am good, thanks`

Comment: `re.sub` the pattern `^[^a-zA-Z]|[^a-zA-Z]$` with empty string?

Comment: My bad, I don't want to substitute all non alphabet chars. For example if I have this string `.,How are you? I am good, thanks .!` I would like to get `How are you? I am good, thanks`

Comment: My regex would do that. Try running it.

Comment: I tried this 
```import re
regex = re.compile('^[^a-zA-Z]|[^a-zA-Z]$ ')
regex.sub('', dirty)```
 and it does not work : / where `dirty = '.,How are you? I am good, thanks .!'`

Comment: @Alan if you want to achieve what is in the comments, you need to change your question too.

Comment: Do you _have_ to use regular expressions? If not, `dirty.strip(string.punctuation)` would work well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the regex:

```
^[^a-zA-Z]+|[^a-zA-Z]+$
```

`[^a-zA-Z]` means "not a-z or A-Z". `^` and `$` refers to the start and end of the string respectively.

Usage:

```
>>> re.sub(r"^[^a-zA-Z]+|[^a-zA-Z]+$", "", ",. Hello, How are you?")
'Hello, How are you'
```

Answer (score 2):

use

```regex
(\w|\s)+
```

which means any `character(\w)` or `space(\s)` with at least a `one-time repeat(+)`.

[***Demo***](https://regex101.com/r/iPnp7I/2)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `strip` function to remove chars from the beginning and end of a string

```
import string
nonalphabet= "".join([c for c in string.printable if c not in string.ascii_letters])
s = ".,how are you ?"
print (s.strip(nonalphabet))
```

would output `how are you`